# EC2 instance Creation using python code problem

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2

im running this code to create an ec2 instance using python but it keeps telling me "You must specify a region."
is there something to add to make it work ?

```
import boto3

def create_ec2_instance():

    try:
         print("Creating EC2 Instance")    
         resource_ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
         resource_ec2.run_instances(
             imageID="ami-051dfed8f67f095f5",
             MinCount=1,
             MaxCount=1,
             InstanceType="t2.micro",
            KeyName="marketing-intelligent"
    )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
create_ec2_instance()
```

Comment: You can save the **default region** by running the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. It will prompt you for information, including the default region to use.

Answer (score 1):

Read your code and try to say in which AWS region this instance will be created. You can't, and neither can `boto3`. You need to provide a region when creating the ec2 client.

```
resource_ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=REGION)
```

where `REGION` is of course one of AWS's regions, e.g `'us-east-1'`.

If you aren't sure, read [AWS Regions and AZs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/).